# iPhone application Passing location coordinates into google places string

Tags: iphone, core-location

In my application i am able to get coordinates of my current location. But there is google places string like

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=52.577798767,-2.124885567&radius=500&types=bank&sensor=false&key=myobfscuredgooglekey"
```

Now how can i pass my dynamic coordinates (if i change my location my coordinates would be new) instead of fixed coordinates?

i want to use this string in

```
NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];

NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
```

googleUrl
i tried my url like this

```
 NSString *googleUrl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f, %f &radius=500&name=man&sensor=false&key=myobscuredgooglekey",a,b];
```

a n b are

```
//a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LATITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.latitude];
//b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LONGITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.longitude];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *googleUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/xml?location=%f,%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude];
```

Use a formatted string using a `CLLocation` retrieved from your `CLLocationManager`. (I omitted some text from the URL to make it shorter.)

Comment: Sorry but i did not understand. at the place os /xml?location=%f,%f"  wot i have to put. i can get location coordinates like ongitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LONGITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.longitude];   latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LATITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.latitude]; bu ti dont want to show them on textfields. i want to use them in my above string

Comment: Yes, which is why you need to take the coordinates from your location manager and insert them into your URL, like I showed above. Afterward, you will have the URL with your coordinates.

Comment: i want to use above string in   NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];
    
    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];

Comment: That would work just fine. Is there a problem with that code?

Comment: Yes it does not show any location.Please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Evan has the right answer but he left out the left side of your url either for brevity or because you really don't need to format the whole string each time.

```
NSString *googleUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f,%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude];
```

You also need to understand that not all coordinate systems speak the same language. Take the exact values you get from location.coordinate.latitute and longituge and **manually** construct the correct url and see if it works. If Evan's code doesn't work verbatim it's a coordination translation issue. Based on the numbers in the URL I would guess it's in Radians but it could be in Decimal Degrees which is what the iPhone returns.